# PHP Script to validate a form entry against MySQL Tables

Tags: php, verification

Newbie here - and I know almost nothing about scripts, so please bear with me.

Through blind trial and error - as well as two solid months worth of reading -  I've found and modified a working script which compares a web form entry known as "EID" to a table which I've created in a MySQL database.

Now, I'd like to up the ante and add more functionality to the script. The web form also contains a box called "Name", which I'd like to verifiy against both an entry in a table called "Name" at the same time the "EID" field is validated.  I could easily check the "Name" entry against yet another database table, however this won't quite do what I need, because each Name is specific to its own EID, and I must be able to verify that the user has entered both a correct name as well as his or her own EID number.  I'm reading that I need to join the two databases in a relational one-to-one scenario to accomplish the server side of this feature, but I haven't a clue how to query such a database setup and return a response.

How can I mod this existing script to check both the Name and EID against these new tables?

Here's my script - I'm sure it's not pretty, but as I said earlier, it does work.

```
<?PHP

class MyCustomValidation extends FM_ExtensionModule
{

    function DoValidate(&$formvars, &$error_hash)
    {
        //connect to DB
        $db = mysql_connect("mydatabase","myaccount ","mypassword");
        if(!$db)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(!mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$db))
        {
           return false;
        }

        //Check the Employee ID Number
        if(!isset($formvars["EID"]))
        {
            $error_hash["EID"]="Please enter a valid Employee ID Number";
            return false;
        }

        $EID = $formvars["EID"];


        $result = mysql_query("select * from EID where EID='$EID'");

        if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
        {
            $error_hash["EID"]="We're sorry, but the Employee ID number you entered, '$EID', was not found in our databases. ";
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Dave The code was there, but invisible because he didn't mark it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (I've left out the check that the `name` field is filled in).

```
$name = $formvars["name"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EID 
                       JOIN users ON EID.EID = users.EID 
                       WHERE EID.EID = '$EID' AND users.name = '$name'");
```

The precise details of the join depend on the names and columns in your tables, but this shows the general idea.

The query will only return a row if the EID exists and its name matches the one entered.

Comment: Thanks! Will the JOIN command affect the tables, or just query both?

Comment: `SELECT` never modifies anything, it just queries. To modify, you have to use `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE`.